# Interesting Append Behavior. Possible Bug?

Tags: modeling

So, I create an object and save it. I then create a new blend and append it. No problem so far.

I resize the appended object to fit the scene. I then duplicate it only for the duplicate to appear at the original size. I cannot get the duplicate to mimic the altered size.

I have tried saving the scene - reopening it and then duplicating but somehow the appended object refuses to forget its original dimensions.

The possible bug I refer to (in the title) is: If, at some point during my modelling I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo changes. My (appended) duplicated and resized duplicates all change back to their original dimensions and clump together.

Is there a way to force an appended object to accept altered dimensions as its default?

Comment: Have you tried applying the size after resizing the object? With "Ctrl-A" you can apply the new size after resizing it in object mode. The adjusted size will become the default (scaling becomes 0). Same counts for applying a new location or rotation when adjusted in object mode. Note that there is a difference between adjusting the size, rotation and location in object mode vs. edit mode. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I edited your "wall of text" to give it more structure and thus make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys - have discovered the problem. There seemed to be an 'animation' attached to the object. Once I deleted this everything works fine. Not sure how the 'animation' came about?